# OAuth2 connection Grant Type "Authorization_code"

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to connect to my Identity Server 4 using the authorization code. I have already successfully connected using the implicit grant type, but I can't find any explicit documentation for the authorization code.

My project is in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC.

Here is my Program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    }).AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.Authority = "https://test.identity.com/";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ClientId = "test_auth";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    });
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

So, I have two questions. Is it possible to connect using 'Authorization_code'?

And the second question: I've seen a lot of documentation where the configuration is in the Startup.ConfigureServices file. Do I need to create it, or does it already exist in .NET Core 8?

I tried many NuGet packages, but none of them worked well.

Error from my identity server :

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgOsG.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8LSP.png)

However, setting a callback path doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You are not setting required parameters. If I remember correctly, the redirect_uri is set based on the `CallbackPath` set in your options. Since you are not setting it, the redirect_uri could be empty or incorrect.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I tried to set the CallbackPath, but that did not solve the problem. Perhaps the issue come from my Identity Server.

Comment: The `invalid redirect_uri` comes from your app or from the identity server? What the actual oauth2 call look like? Edit your question and provide the uri your app sets when redirecting to the identity server. It should look like `https://identity.server.....?response_type=code&client_id=...&redirect_uri=....&scope=...`

Comment: @WiktorZychla Edited the post with callbackpath and image error

Comment: Now it seems that setting the correct callback path solved the problem. If this is so, at least edit your question to not to mislead anyone reading the last sentence.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The problème came from the identity serveur properties, i use entityframework for configuration and the redirect uri in the database was wrong. Callback path didnt change anything but, i let thé callback path in configuration for anyone note using entityframework as configuration. But thanks for your help 

Answer (score 1):

The problems originated from the redirect URI properties in my identity server, which needed to be set as follows:

[Database RedirectUri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4yDk.png)

And for the openIdConnect Configuration, like this :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
}).AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://test.identityserver.com/";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.ClientId = "test_auth";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
});
```